# SSRS Expression - #Error in an obviously correct expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS expression with this in it:

```
=IIF(
    Fields!CUT.Value.ToString().Length > 1
    ,IIF(
        Fields!CUT.Value.ToString().Contains(","), 
        Fields!CUT.Value.ToString().Substring(0, Fields!CUT.Value.ToString().IndexOf(",")),
        Fields!CUT.Value.ToString()
    )
    ,""
)
```

**Translation:**
If the field contains a `,`, Get me the `substring` of the field from the first position to where the `,` is. If the field does not contain `,`, just get me the entire field.

**Probelm:**
I get a `#Error` in all the pages where there is NO COMMA. If there is a COMMA, it works as expected. One of the fields, the value is `4`. In a different scenario, the value is `17/64" Corrugated`. I get an error for both of those.

**What I've tried:**
I've tried a few different approaches:

1. Used `LIKE` instead of `Contains`

   ```
   =IIF(
       IsNothing(Fields!CUT.Value)
       ,""
       ,IIF(
           Fields!CUT.Value LIKE "*,*", 
           Mid(Fields!CUT.Value, InStr(Fields!CUT.Value, ",") + 1,  (LEN(Fields!CUT.Value) - InStr(Fields!CUT.Value, ",") - 1))
           Fields!CUT.Value
       )
   )
   ```
2. I added a new field to my `dataset` that replaces `,` with `XXXX`. I thought, maybe SSRS is not able to understand that I am talking about a `,` as a part of the string. And then changed the query to see if there is an `XXXX` in it. Still got the same `#Error`
3. Delete the `.data` file, cleaned the project, and rebuilt the project. Because, this is so obviously not incorrect. So I thought maybe it is not looking at the latest version of the report.

Nothing seems to do it! I am really close to doing something bad! This thing is driving me insane.

**Questions:**

1. Anyone see anything wrong with either of my expressions?
2. Is there a better way to do to what I am trying to accomplish? If there is a `,`, give me everything before the `,`. If not, give me everything.

**Edit 1:**
Worth noting that, in a different field, I am doing something very similar to this:

```
IIF(
    IsNothing(Fields!CUT.Value)
    ,""
    ,IIF(
        Fields!CUT.Value LIKE "*,*"
        ," | Length: " & Mid(Fields!CUT.Value, InStr(Fields!CUT.Value, ",") + 1,  (LEN(Fields!CUT.Value) - InStr(Fields!CUT.Value, ",") - 1))
        ,""
    )
)
```

What this is doing is, if there is a `,` in that very same field, get me everything AFTER the `,` and append it to `| Length:`. If there is no `,`, just show an empty space `""`. This works perfectly fine. In situations where there is a `,` and where there is NO `,`. So I've concluded that Microsoft is using SSRS to make me go crazy.

Comment: SSRS evaluates all portions of the `IIF` regardless of whether the first statement is true or false, so your issue most likely lies in your true section: `Fields!CUT.Value.ToString().Substring(0, Fields!CUT.Value.ToString().IndexOf(","))`. If there is no comma, then this expression won't be able to find the position of the comma. But I'm not sure exactly how the `IndexOf` function behaves, and I don't have the means to test it at the moment, so leaving this as just a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using SWITCH and test for no comma first but there is a much easier way assuming you only ever want to get the first part of the string up to the point of the comma.

This just uses the split function and takes the first element.

```
=(Split(Fields!CUT.Value, ",")).GetValue(0)
```

Nice and simple :)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think of using `Switch`. That would have been definitely easier. But I've already changed my stored procedure to return results in two different fields so I don't have to worry about it in SSRS. I am still probably going to try yours out, for future reference. Thanks

Comment: Marking as answer even though I didn't use this because, this definitely works. Both `Switch` and `Split` works. But I've already made some major changes to the stored procedure. So I am going to go with that.Thank you.